# Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy - swift

Tags: swift2, ios9

I am getting this error/warning and did not find any answer to this. The thing is I have two code files: **ViewController.swift** and **CoreLocationDelegate.swift**.

In the following code (CoreLocationDelegate.swift) you will find a **showLocationServicesDeniedAlert()** method. Which is being called in **getLocation()**.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class CoreLocationDelegate: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("didFailWithError: \(error)")
  }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let newLocation = locations.last!
    print("didUpdateLocations: \(newLocation)")
  }

  // MARK: getLocation method

  func getLocation() {

    // Check for current authorisation status of app:
    let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authStatus == .NotDetermined {
      locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      return
    }

    if authStatus == .Denied || authStatus == .Restricted {
      showLocationServicesDeniedAlert()
    }

    // Get current location
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

  }

  func showLocationServicesDeniedAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services Disabled", message: "Please enable location services for this app in Settings.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

Now here the issue arises in using the getLocation() method inside a button in the following code (ViewController.swift):

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        @IBAction func getLocationButton(sender: AnyObject) {
            CoreLocationDelegate().getLocation()        
        }

    }
```

When pressing the button (In the simulator) I get the **Warning: Attempt to present on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Any idea what I am missing or need to grasp?

Comment: `CoreLocationDelegate().getLocation()` creates a new `CoreLocationDelegate` object which is not presented or displayed, in other words, not part of the window hierarchy.  If it then tries to present something, there's no context for that presentation.

Comment: Oh! I did this because CoreLocation.getLocation() gave me a 'Missing argument for parameter #1 in call' error. 

When I changed it to CoreLocationDelegate().getLocation() it did work until I added the showLocationServicesDeniedAlert() method.

Comment: That makes sense because getLocation() doesn't try to present anything otherwise.  I suspect that ViewController is the class that should be showing the alert based on something returned from getLocation().